# Can JS.Class classes extend classes from other libraries?

Tags: javascript, js.class

#### Premise

I've inherited some code that uses [JS.Class](http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/) for some of it's classes.  That is, these classes are created using `new JS.Class({...})`.  JS.Class implements Ruby's object system in JavaScript, meaning that internally it is rather complex.

I am writing new code that uses [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) Models and Collections.  Backbone.js uses the predominant style of JS class inheritance: simple prototype chaining.  It's almost identical to the style of Google's Closure library (`goog.inherits()`) and CoffeeScript (`class Foo extends Bar`).

#### My question, directed at anyone with JS.Class experience:

Can I use JS.Class to extend non-JS.Class classes?  For example, can I create a JS.Class that extends Backbone.Model?  Or goog.gears.BaseStore? (just to choose two examples of classes from common JS libraries)